# Create a Maven Enterprise Application using NetBeans 8.2

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to create a Java Maven Enterprise Application using NetBeans 8.2, but I can't find the "Maven Enterprise Application"-option.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here: `File > New Project > Maven > Enterprise Application`

[image: netbeans 8.2]

Comment: @KhayelihleKunene maven is just a software project management and comprehension tool. Maven has multiple applications and "enterprise application" is one of them. What do you suggest if the difference between "maven enterprise application" and "maven enterprise application"?